# Проблема с переводом приложения через NSLocalized

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, локализация

Возникла проблема при локализации приложения под iPhone, поддержку языков подключил, в файле с локализацией всё прописал - вначале работала поддержка 3 языков. на следующий день пришёл, запуслил это же приложение, симулятор не видит ключи. Использую XCode 5.0.2 | Simulator iOS 7, 6.1, 6 - на реальном устройстве не проверял.

Локализацию задаю так:

```
self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO", "title");
```

В файле прописанно так:

```
"HELLO" = "Привет";
```

В чём проблема может быть?

**Обновление**

Проблема была в другом, XCode файлы видел, но не хотел их читать, после пересоздания файлом всё стало на свои места

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте конфигурацию проекта, вы же наверное это все делаете в xCode, а он на этом отжигать мастер, особенно после обновлений.
 [image]

Если там все нормально, либо пересоздайте в этой менюшке локализацию файлов, либо похерьте индексы проекта и переиндексируйте проджект.